# convert get of lodash javascript library to optional chaining

Tags: lodash, optional-chaining

I wanted to change this code which is using get method from lodash library to optional chaining method.Can someone help me to convert this

```
return get(
          this.UIObj,
          'excelList',
          []
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional return the `excelList` property of `this.UIObj`, and if it's `undefined` (or `null`) return an empty array using the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
return this.UIObj?.excelList ?? []
```